# is it possible to only first section fixed in tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an viewcontroller with tableView. I want to create design like AppStore App detail page. My tableView's first section has segmentedControl so it fixes to top. Other sections have title, other sections pushes first section when user scroll tableView.

I want to fixed to top only first section other sections slip to up.

[image]

[image]

I have try some code but I did not find any solution.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue. 
I ended up using separated `UIView` so basically I detect scrollview current position if the y is bigger than section height I show my `UIView`.

so basically I implemented the `UIScrollView` method

`func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

and I wrote

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > mySeparatedView.frame.size.height) {
    mySeparatedView.isHidden = false
} else {
    mySection.isHidden = true
}
```

or simply put

```
mySection.isHidden = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > mySeparatedView.frame.size.height) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put segmentedControl in tableView. Put segmentedControl outside of `UITableview` on Top of Tableview.